# Response Order in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, concurrency

I've gone through some introductory articles on Node.js and Event Loop and one thing is not clear - if there are multiple concurrent requests then are the responses always sequential in the order the request was made? Say if 20 requests did complete simultaneously then will the 20th response have to wait for the other 19 to be cleared (responded back to the client) ?

Update: What I was wondering is whether this is similar to how multiple setTimeouts get queued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node.js runs Javascript as single threaded.  Thus, only one piece of Javascript is running at any given time.

But, almost all I/O (e.g. networking, file access, etc...) is asynchronous and non-blocking.  So, if 20 requests are made of your server in a very short period of time, the first request to reach the server will start executing it's request handler and the other requests will be queued.  But, as soon as the first request hits an asynchronous operation (such as reading from the local file system), that request will be suspended while the non-blocking asynchronous I/O is taking place and the next request in line will start to run.

This second request will then run until it either finishes or until it also hits a piece of asynchronous I/O.  When that second request is waiting on the async I/O, then another request will get to run.  The system scheduler will determine if the next operation is the completion of the async I/O request from the first request or if it will start the third request that was waiting in the queue.

The various requests will continue this way until all are done.  Multiple requests may be "in-flight" at the same time (meaning they've been started, but have not completed yet), but only one is ever actually executing code at any given moment.

This is sometimes referred to as cooperative tasking.  There is no pre-emptive multi-tasking among the different requests where each automatically gets a time slice of the host CPU.  But, any time a request hits an asynchronous I/O operation, then that tells the scheduler that other requests waiting to run can run.

This is all managed from an event queue in node.js.  A piece of Javascript runs until it completes.  If it makes an asynchronous I/O request and then completes, then another piece of Javascript that is also waiting to run can start to run.  When it is done, the JS engine pulls the next item out of the event queue and runs it.  That might be a new incoming request or it might be the completion of some asynchronous I/O operation on some other request.

The advantages of this type of system are:

1. It scales really well, particularly for I/O bound server operations, because you can have many requests "in-flight" at the same time with only a single Javascript thread.  The cooperative tasking is very lightweight and fast.
2. Programming a system like this has far fewer "race conditions" to watch out for because no two pieces of Javascript are ever running at the actual same time.  This means you can often share state between requests without ever having to use mutexes (like you would in a multi-thread environment).  Since thread-safe bugs are often very difficult to avoid and to test for, it's a major advantage to eliminate these types of bugs.
3. The cooperative model is conceptually simple and easier to learn and to program safely.

The disadvantages of this type of system are:

1. It does not share the CPU among tasks that are CPU-bound.  A node.js programmer with lots of heavy CPU-bound computations often has to use clustering or child processes to handle the heave CPU computations so as to not over-burden the main request processing Javascript thread with that work and make it too non-responsive.
2. Clustering of processes is required to maximize the use of multiple processors and then any shared data must be shared across those processes.  People often use an in-memory database like Redis to share data between processes.
3. You can't just willy nilly fire up another Javascript thread to go off and do something.

Comment: Awesome answer. Could you please add a little more detail regarding processes that are treated as Asynchronous and those who are not treated as asynchronous.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite - In node.js pretty much any library function that delivers its result in a callback function is asynchronous.  For example [`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) is asynchronous.  [`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options) is synchronous.  It will usually be obvious based on the interface or documentation of the function, but it IS something you must know in order to use the function appropriately.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite - Asynchronous operations must be based on an underlying operation that is carried out asynchronous in native code since you cannot write a true asynchronous operation from scratch in node.js.  You must either based it on existing asynchronous operations or you must create a native code plug-in that implements the operation asynchronously and then calls a callback later with the results.

Comment: @jfriend00 bit confused here.. So if 3 responses complete their asynchronous activity and are back to the server/event loop at the same time, they are picked sequentially? The last of the three that gets picked and returned to the client has  some wait time?

Comment: @Kodathon - Yes.  it is an event queue.  Items are picked out of the queue one at a time as it is their turn.  node.js runs only one piece of Javascript at a time so if one is running, then others wait in the event queue until it is their turn.